# Why joining same table twice returns different column values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a stored procedure that was not written by me.

I cannot understand how they are joining the same table `tblUsers` twice and it returns different column values:

```
select distinct 
    usr.Name_FirstLast AS AssignedTo,
    usr1.Name_FirstLast as AssignedBy 
from 
    dbo.tblNoteStore  nt_str
join 
    dbo.tblNoteEntities entit ON nt_str.ID = entit.NoteGUID
join
    dbo.tblNoteDiaries nt_dia ON nt_str.ID = nt_dia.NoteGUID
join
    dbo.tblNoteEntries entri on nt_str.ID = entri.NoteGUID
                             and nt_dia.EntryGUID = entri.ID 
                             and entit.NoteGUID = entri.NoteGUID
left join 
    dbo.tblNoteRecipients recip ON entri.ID = recip.EntryGUID
--this is where the same table used twice 
left join 
    dbo.tblUsers  usr ON recip.UserGUID = usr.UserGUID   -- returns AssignedTo column
left join
    dbo.tblUsers usr1 ON usr1.UserGuid = entri.UserGUID   -- returns AssignedBy column
where 
    usr.UserGUID = '55610B2F-1997-40C0-9F01-EED3ED2939F9'
```

The result is what I need, but why it happens that way?

- `dbo.tblUsers` has primary key `UserGUID`
- `dbo.tblNoteEntries` has a foreign key `UserGUID`
- `dbo.tblNoteRecipients` has a foreign key `UserGUID`

[image]

Also, do I have to use all those tables in `JOIN` in order to receive the result?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why joining same table twice on two different columns returns different column values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781241/why-joining-same-table-twice-on-two-different-columns-returns-different-column-v)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblUsers  usr ON recip.UserGUID = usr.UserGUID --    > gives me AssignedTo column
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblUsers usr1 ON usr1.UserGuid = entri.UserGUID--gives me AssignedBy column
```

The UserGUID column of the 2 `dbo.tblUsers` table references are correlated using different columns (`recip.UserGUID` and `entri.UserGUID`) so different rows from `dbo.tblUsers` may be returned.