# Why joining same table twice on two different columns returns different column values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a stored procedure that was not written by me.

I cannot understand how they are joining the same table `tblUsers` twice and it returns different column values:

```
select distinct 
    usr.Name_FirstLast AS AssignedTo,
    usr1.Name_FirstLast as AssignedBy 
from 
    dbo.tblNoteStore  nt_str
join 
    dbo.tblNoteEntities entit ON nt_str.ID = entit.NoteGUID
join
    dbo.tblNoteDiaries nt_dia ON nt_str.ID = nt_dia.NoteGUID
join
    dbo.tblNoteEntries entri on nt_str.ID = entri.NoteGUID
                             and nt_dia.EntryGUID = entri.ID 
                             and entit.NoteGUID = entri.NoteGUID
left join 
    dbo.tblNoteRecipients recip ON entri.ID = recip.EntryGUID
--this is where the same table used twice 
left join 
    dbo.tblUsers  usr ON recip.UserGUID = usr.UserGUID   -- returns AssignedTo column
left join
    dbo.tblUsers usr1 ON usr1.UserGuid = entri.UserGUID   -- returns AssignedBy column
where 
    usr.UserGUID = '55610B2F-1997-40C0-9F01-EED3ED2939F9'
```

The result is what I need, but why it happens that way?

- `dbo.tblUsers` has primary key `UserGUID`
- `dbo.tblNoteEntries` has a foreign key `UserGUID`
- `dbo.tblNoteRecipients` has a foreign key `UserGUID`

[image]

Also, do I have to use all those tables in `JOIN` in order to receive the result?

Comment: Get consistent on which table you put on the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with clean up syntax and put the same table on left

```
select distinct 
       usr.Name_FirstLast  AS AssignedTo 
     , usr1.Name_FirstLast as AssignedBy 
from tblNoteStore      nt_str
join tblNoteEntities   entit 
      ON entit.NoteGUID  = nt_str.ID  
join tblNoteDiaries  nt_dia 
      ON nt_dia.NoteGUID = nt_str.ID 
join tblNoteEntries    entri 
      on entri.NoteGUID = nt_str.ID 
     and entri.NoteGUID = entit.NoteGUID
     and entri.ID       = nt_dia.EntryGUID           
join tblNoteRecipients recip 
      ON recip.EntryGUID = entri.ID   
join tblUsers          usr 
      ON usr.UserGUID  = recip.UserGUID   -- returns AssignedTo column
join tblUsers          usr1 
      ON usr1.UserGuid = entri.UserGUID   -- returns AssignedBy column
where usr.UserGUID = '55610B2F-1997-40C0-9F01-EED3ED2939F9'
```

this is silly on so many levels

tblUsers is the PK there is absolutely not reason to left to join to it

usr.UserGUID = '55610B2F-1997-40C0-9F01-EED3ED2939F9'  was killing the left join

from 
   join tblNoteEntities entit 
          ON entit.NoteGUID  = nt_str.ID

we know `entit.NoteGUID  = nt_str.ID`
but you are repeating

```
 join tblNoteEntries entri 
      on entri.NoteGUID = nt_str.ID 
     and entri.NoteGUID = entit.NoteGUID
```

the best sense I can make of this

```
select distinct 
       usr.Name_FirstLast  AS AssignedTo 
     , usr1.Name_FirstLast as AssignedBy 
from tblNoteStore      nt_str
join tblNoteEntities   entit 
      ON entit.NoteGUID  = nt_str.ID  
join tblNoteDiaries    nt_dia 
      ON nt_dia.NoteGUID = nt_str.ID 
join tblNoteEntries    entri 
      on entri.NoteGUID  = nt_str.ID 
     and entri.ID        = nt_dia.EntryGUID           
join tblNoteRecipients recip 
      ON recip.EntryGUID = entri.ID   
join tblUsers          usr 
      ON usr.UserGUID  = recip.UserGUID   -- returns AssignedTo column
     and usr.UserGUID = '55610B2F-1997-40C0-9F01-EED3ED2939F9'
join tblUsers          usr1 
      ON usr1.UserGuid = entri.UserGUID   -- returns AssignedBy column
```

Comment: #Paparazzi
Thank you very much. I think I finally got it.
Thanks

Comment: #Paparazzi. I am amazed how you cracked up this JOIN. I know how joins differentiate and works but those complicated ones are confusing me. Is there any kind of rule of thumb you using? How to understand this logic?
Like what do you mean by "putting same table on a left"?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because the user table is joined to two differents tables.

```
left join 
    dbo.tblUsers  usr ON recip.UserGUID = usr.UserGUID
```

joins to the alias `recip` which stand for `dbo.tblNoteRecipients`, where as

```
left join
    dbo.tblUsers usr1 ON usr1.UserGuid = entri.UserGUID
```

joins to the alias `entri` which stand for `dbo.tblNoteEntries`.

Note that these two aliases are declared in previous joins:

```
                         |
join                     V
    dbo.tblNoteEntries entri on nt_str.ID = entri.NoteGUID
                             and nt_dia.EntryGUID = entri.ID 
                             and entit.NoteGUID = entri.NoteGUID
left join 
    dbo.tblNoteRecipients recip ON entri.ID = recip.EntryGUID
                            ^
                            |
```